# Certificate Transparency Logs for C#

Tags: c#, certificate, x509certificate, certificate-transparency

Currently working on a certificate transparency logs. My goal is to read each log just like what [CertStream](https://certstream.calidog.io/) - (Open the fire hose button) did, my boss wants to create another one that is written in C#. Just a simple code to parse the logs can really help me. Not necessarily as fancy as CertStream does its stuff.

**These are the following links/APIs that I've read:**
(API's from Google or related)

- https://ct.googleapis.com/pilot/ct/v1/get-sth
- https://ct.googleapis.com/logs/argon2020/ct/v1/get-entries?start=20200201&end=20200205
- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6962

Valuable info:

- https://certstream.calidog.io/
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59772797/cant-parse-precertificate-from-certificate-transparency-log

For the code I started,

```
 byte[] byte_LeafInput = Convert.FromBase64String(leaf_input);
 byte[] byte_extradata = Convert.FromBase64String(extra_data);
 string strLeafInput = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byte_LeafInput);
 string strExtraData = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byte_extradata);
```

But it only shows some gibberish data with few readable words.
[image]

Any codes or libraries that can help me with that? Upon searching, I found so many codes written in different languages like Python, Go, etc., but based on what I understand in their code, they are also using libraries which is not available in NuGet. X509Certificate might be useful but I don't know how to use it in this case.

Any lead would really be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Sadly SO isn't really a place to recommend articles; tools or libraries.  [ask]. I must say you started off quite good by listing some interesting articles in your second paragraph.  Good luck

Comment: @MickyD okay. let me modify my question. thank you for your prompt reply. :)

Answer (score 0):

Upon searching for a long time. My boss advised me to get the logs and parse it through Python and save that in a text file or csv. After that, my program in C# can use all functions to analyze the information in the created text file. I guess using the current wheel is more efficient than creating one. :)